# Why 'react-hook-form' gives empty data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am working in react-native and used 'react-hook-forms' for dynamic form creation,
but it's returning empty data object, but it should return values typed in input fields. onSubmit function gives an empty values. Please check my below code. please help me...

//InputBox.js.  this my dynamic element where I want  access its values in AddDirectries.js

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
const InputBox = ({ fields, fieldName }) => {
    let { control } = useForm();
    return (
        <>
            { fields.field_unit == null ? <Text style={styles.formsTitle}>{fieldName}</Text> :
                <Text style={styles.formsTitle}> {fieldName + "(" + fields.field_unit + ")"}</Text>

            }

            {[...Array(fields.field_count)].map((item, index) => {
                return (

                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name={'j' + index}
                        defaultValue=""
                        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                            <TextInput
                                onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                                value={value}
                            ></TextInput>

                        )}
                    />
                )
            })
            })
        </>)
}
export default InputBox;
```

//AddDirectries.js here I want access TextInput values.

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import Element from '../components/Element'
import FormJson from '../../From.json'
export const AddDirectories = (props) => {
    let { handleSubmit, control, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
    useEffect(() => {
        setKeys(Object.keys(FormJson))
        setElements(FormJson)
    }, [])
    return (
        <View style={[styles.mainScreen, { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }]}>
                {
                    keys.map((fieldName, index) => {
                        return <Element fieldName={fieldName} fields={elements[keys[index]]} key={index}></Element>
                    })
                }
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={[styles1.addButton, { marginBottom: 30 }]}>
                    <Text>ADD</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

//Element.js

```
const Element = ({fieldName, fields }) => {
    switch (fields.field_type) {
        case ("TextField"):
                return (<InputLocation fields ={fields} fieldName={fieldName} />)
        default: return null;
    }
}
export default Element;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
instead of :

```
<Controller
                        control={control}
                        name={'j' + index}
                        defaultValue=""
                        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                            <TextInput
                                onChangeText={value => onChange(value)}
                                value={value}
                            ></TextInput>

                        )}
                    />
```

spread field into textinput:

```
<Controller
                        control={control}
                        name={'j' + index}
                        defaultValue=""
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <TextInput
                                {...field}
                                onChangeText={value => field.onChange(value)}
                                value={field.value}
                            ></TextInput>

                        )}
                    />
```

Comment: thank you for the responce but it gives an error.....ReferenceError: Can't find variable: field

Comment: just edited it so it won't deconstruct the field like you did before and now it should work

Comment: still not working, it gives an empty object again

Comment: please check  my code InputBox is child component Element and Element is iterating from map of AddDirectries,js